# Remapping properties in inheritance map class

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have a base map class(in its own assembly), where Segment property was declared as **LazyLoad**.

```
public class GroupMap : ClassMap<Group>
{
    public GroupMap()
    {
        ....

        Map(x => x.Segment)
            .LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

In my application I want this property not to be a LazyLoad. I tried some methods like this:

```
public class MyGroupMap : GroupMap
{
    public MyGroupMap() : base()
    {
        Map(x => x.Segment)
            .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

And Adding this class to Mappings. But it only generates a runtime exception(Property Segment was already mapped. Obvious). Any suggestions? I think Properties property might help, but it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get an answer in fluent nhibernate google-group.
The main idea is to create a base mapping class(GroupMapBase) with main properties mapped. Also GroupMap class with lazyload properties.
And the MyGroupMap class based on GroupMapBase where needed properties Mapped without lazyloading.

It solved my problem.